# How to combine two columns in pandas dataframe and set values to them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two columns in pandas dataframe ***Latitude*** and ***Longitude***. I am trying two combine them in single column ***LOCATION***.
If we see the data there are only two locations are present.

**Input:**

```
LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
29.14290089 -100.73896686
29.142901   -100.738967
29.14290089 -100.73896686
29.142901   -100.738967
29.14290089 -100.73896686
29.142901   -100.738967
29.14290089 -100.73896686
```

**Expected Output:**

```
LOCATION
Loc_1
Loc_2
Loc_1
Loc_2
Loc_1
Loc_2
Loc_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['LOCATION'] = pd.factorize(df[['LATITUDE','LONGITUDE']].apply(tuple, 1))[0] + 1

df['LOCATION'] = 'Loc_' + df['LOCATION'].astype(str)
print (df)
    LATITUDE   LONGITUDE LOCATION
0  29.142901 -100.738967    Loc_1
1  29.142901 -100.738967    Loc_2
2  29.142901 -100.738967    Loc_1
3  29.142901 -100.738967    Loc_2
4  29.142901 -100.738967    Loc_1
5  29.142901 -100.738967    Loc_2
6  29.142901 -100.738967    Loc_1
```

Comment: I am getting NaN in LOC column. also can we do it dynamic. because we may don't know if the values in LAT and LONG will be same.

Comment: @sheel - if no match it means values are different, what means dynamic?

Comment: It seems like LATITUDE and LONGITUDE have been rounded to hold five figures after the decimal point, and there is no difference between the LOCATION of Loc_1 and Loc_2.

Comment: @jezrael dynamic means, above I have just shown two locations(coordinates) in future dataset they might be different  or more than two. so how can we handle those situation.

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi - it is only display issue ;)

Comment: @jezarel - I agree, however it seems like it is (maybe) the same issue that is facing in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
locs = {(29.14290089, -100.73896686) : "Loc_1",
        (29.142901, -100.738967) : "Loc_2"}

out = df.apply(tuple, axis=1).map(locs)
print(out)

0    Loc_1
1    Loc_2
2    Loc_1
3    Loc_2
4    Loc_1
5    Loc_2
6    Loc_1
dtype: object
```

If you want it as new column in your `df` just do:

```
df['LOCATION'] = df.apply(tuple, axis=1).map(locs)
```

Comment: I have LAT and LONG in data-frame in two diffrent column rather than in a tuple. can we implement that? something like this out = df.apply(df['LATITUDE','LONGITUDE'], axis=1)

Comment: therefore is `df.apply(tuple, axis=1)` it creates a tuple of the values of these two columns (for comparison). The two columns of your dataframe with LAT and LONG don't change